# extracting csv download link from an webpage using python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the CSV download URL from website - https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBJ1J.png)

Code I used till now

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 
"equity_underlyingVal")))
nifty = (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//* 
[@id="equity_underlyingVal"]').text).replace('NIFTY ', 
'').replace(',','')
time_stamp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//* 
[@id="equity_timeStamp"]').text
```

I need the csv link to be load in pandas df. I dont want to use selenium or if using selenium, I need it as headless. Let me know if anyone has a better idea about extracting data directly into pandas datafream..

Comment: Can you post the code you made so far and where did you get stuck ?

Comment: I have edited the post and added the code, also I added one image describing the target link which I need to extract

Comment: why not to click on "Download (.csv)" with selenium and write a code that go to the place the file is downloaded and read the file?

Comment: I tried using click event as in headless option, but its not working there. I want it to be run in background process.. with out opening chrome driver, that's why if anyhow I get the direct csv link, then I can read it using pandas read csv method

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the downloading link contained in that element with Selenium as following:

```py
link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#downloadOCTable').get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: The link to the csv is not available in the `href` attribute. It uses JavaScript.

Comment: I have copied it directly from the element attribute and pasted on the new blank tab and clicked enter - the csv file was downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the download link is not present in the `href` attribute, the best approach is to download the csv file.

Interacting in headless mode can cause problems if the `window-size` argument is not specified, and a workaround to download files in `headless` mode is to specify the download path using the `driver.command_executor` method.

Code snippet to download csv in headless mode-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os

options = Options()

#add necessary arguments
options.add_argument("user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

#set download path (set to current working directory in this example)
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow','downloadPath':os.getcwd()}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain")

#wait for table details to appear
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="equity_optionChainTable"]')))

#find and click on download csv button
download_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadOCTable"]')
download_button.click()
```

Comment: I tried using this code, but its not working properly. some time it download 1kb of file csv file. Can you hold the browser while download has not finished?

Comment: I changed the XPATH in this section  - #wait for table details to appear

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="equity_underlyingVal"]')))`

now it is working for me. thanks @Kamalesh S